# Java Passing variables, avoiding toString hash

Tags: java, class, variables, integer

I know this has been asked before, but not in a way I understood, because I am dumb.

So.

I need to take some variables into a class, compare them against something, and then return the higher of the two. In the long run, I need to compare against a running total, but for my problem, I think the issue is considerably more fundamental. I'm not understanding how to pass a variable BACK to my main class.

```
import java.io.*;
public class testing123 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   

    Integer  a;
    Integer  b;
    Integer numbersCombined;
    try {
          System.out.println("Please enter a number");
          a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

          System.out.println("Please enter a number");
          b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());


          numbersCombined = (a + b);




      testClass Check = new testClass();

      System.out.println("Your numbers combined is " +numbersCombined);
      System.out.println(Check);

    } catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error reading from user");
    }

  }

}

class testClass {
  public static Integer testClass (Integer numbersCombined) {


if (numbersCombined > 100) {
  numbersCombined = numbersCombined;
}
else {
  numbersCombined = 100;
}
System.out.println(numbersCombined);
return numbersCombined;
  }
}
```

If I remove the return, this will print the numbersCombined, but that's all it does. With the return in place, it doesn't execute the print line above the return, and first prints the original numbersCombined (which it shouldn't if you use, say, 10 and 20, since that's less than 100), and then prints testClass@76046e53 rather than the actual value. I know there's a way to override it, but the answers I've found don't work for me.

I know this answer: http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F29140402%2Fhow-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGIzxlBSH8xIS7hurKe6_Euc7B8RQ

is the basic problem I'm encountering, but the overrides listed aren't really working for me, and I want integer anyway, rather than string.

In the end, what I'm "really" doing is taking a series of 4 numbers from a user, then using this function to compare whether THIS series of numbers is higher than the previous maximum, and if it is, that's the new maximum moving forward, with a loop until the user is done entering serieses of 4 numbers, and then finally printing the maximum.

I was able to write this without ANY functions, all inline, easy as pie. But once I send the comparison to a function, I don't understand how to send it back, and I've spent all day trying to understand the concept. ALL DAY. So, while I know it's going to be a stupid answer, that's because I'm stupid, but not because I didn't try (sorry, kind of defensive. Frustrated).

Fundamentally, I want to send two (this example is just one) variables to a class, compare them, change ONE of them, and return it to the main class. In this example, I'm just trying to send ONE variable, compare it, and the send it back.

Comment: Did you try calling your method in `testClass`?  It does return an integer, which seems like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method within TestClass. Your code is already returning an integer from that method.

Once you instantiate the class run `testClass.testClass(numbers)`

The way you're throwing around pseudo-global variables between classes is probably the problem. Pass them through the calls like above, rather than implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   

        Integer  a;
        Integer  b;
        Integer numbersCombined;
        try {
          System.out.println("Please enter a number");
          a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

          System.out.println("Please enter a number");
          b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

          numbersCombined = (a + b);

          testClass Check = new testClass(numbersCombined); // constructor should be like this

          System.out.println("Your numbers combined is " + numbersCombined);
          System.out.println(Check);

        } catch (IOException e){
          System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }

     }
}

class testClass {
  Integer numbersCombined;

  // This is a constructor
  public testClass (Integer numbersCombined) {
    if (numbersCombined > 100) {
      this.numbersCombined = numbersCombined; // use this to represent the object
    } else {
      this.numbersCombined = 100;
    }
    System.out.println(numbersCombined);
  }

  // Add method toString()
  public String toString() {
      return this.numbersCombined.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: When I copy and paste that code, I get an error: [line 21]Error: constructor testClass in class testClass cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.lang.Integer reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You should pass the Integer element in constructor:
new testClass(numbersCombined);

if you pass only "new testClass()", so the compiler will throw an error. Unless you create a new constructor without any arguments